# Tips for cooking a classic French omelette in a carbon steel pan

Tags: carbon-steel

Are there any specific tricks or tips for cooking a classic French omelette in a carbon steel pan?

Comment: How is it different from using a nonstick pan?

Comment: What are the problems you are having @whiz? What is the method you have tried? This question is a bit vague.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue in cooking a french omelet **in carbon steel it'll stick too much**. As I was taught you should just try to use a different pan but **if you must use that kind** then be sure to **properly lubricate the pan with fat before** adding egg. Then **again if and when the eggs absorb it**. Then to **change it on to a lower heat than typically** then making a french omlete so that it will not burn or get stuck as easily. **Be sure to cook it long enough so that the bottom is firm enough** not to break **before moving it**. With the excess fat it should release from the pan much like meat does. **Once it has released** from the pan be sure to **keep it moving** so that it will not stick again.